# Google Sheets : simple query with pivot clause

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, formula

I can't find a way to simplify a query to get a similar result to a pivot.
Although a pivot table is easy, I would prefer to use a query because I can then personalise headers.

Here's the link with the data :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R461nv2lD4efpuUuDonFMYGnLH510n7gwpbzG2WAUaw/edit?usp=sharing.

This is the working embedded queries :

```
= query(query(Data!A1:C, " SELECT B,count(B) WHERE B is not null GROUP BY B,C ORDER BY B ASC "), "SELECT Col1, Count(Col1) group by Col1 LABEL Col1 'Status',Count(Col1) 'Count'",1 )
```

This is the query I'd like to use with a pivot clause :

```
=query(Data!A1:C, "Select B, count(C) group by count(C)  Pivot C" ,1)
```

Here's what I'm looking for :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
={"Status","Count(Categories)";transpose(query(unique(B:C),"select count(Col2) where Col2 is not null pivot Col1",1))}
```

[image]

or simplier

```
=query(unique(B:C),"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1",1)
```

[image]

Comment: interesting, @Mike Steelson.
I was looking for something more simple, closer to the last formula I used.
Not sure it's even possible.

Comment: simplier : `=query(unique(B:C),"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1",1)` - I added in the answer

Comment: This simplifier is a very neat solution !
Thank you so much,@Mike Steelson !

Comment: How can I make this work if the columns are not contiguous (without using helper columns) ?

I ask because that formula would be used several times for different columns in the same data range. I hope to avoid building an embedded query again.

Comment: if columns are not continous, for instance C and E, you can juxtapose C and E by a comma and write `=query(unique({C:C,E:E}),"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1",1)`

Comment: I was just trying that, but with the wrong syntax :/
Thank you again : this will help a lot building my dashboard with many different metrics.

Comment: BTW, I never realized one could use formulas for defining the ranges inside queries.
Humbling experience, lol.

Comment: happy to solve the issue - content d'avoir contribué à résoudre le sujet (signé Michel .. too)

Comment: hehe ! Thanks again for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pivot C column it should be:

```
=QUERY({Data!A1:C, Data!C1:C}, 
 "select Col2,count(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col4", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't give the required result

Comment: @Michel in that case you do not need to use pivot(C) eg. your question is misleading

Comment: You're possibly right.
I tried to replicate this demo which seems similar, except it has 3 columns headers.
https://youtu.be/LMah09md9o8?t=268